# Retrieve source in manifest from Org

Tags: apex, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I'm trying to retrieve classes from my test org using package.xml. Recently the operation fails immediately with the following error;

10:35:14.995 Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org

Socket is closed

I'm not sure what's causing this as it's worked fine previously, has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Did you try executing same command just from Salesforce CLI?

Comment: I didn't, i'm not sure what command i should run as i'm using VSCode, so i normally right click the package.xml in my project folder and click retrieve source from Org.

Comment: The VSCode output panel shows what command. We want to see what's causing it (CLI or VSCode extension)to file a bug if turns out to be bug.

Comment: Hi, I ran the retrieve command in the terminal and it appears it's received my apex classes. So it means it's an issue with VSCode?

Comment: Yes, I would reinstall the extensions to see if this fixes it

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.Under Windows there is HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables registred, I have removed them and restarted my machin and finally the command works now.And I am able to retrieve my source code from Org.